# Last-child selector is not working if last li is a link

Tags: html, css

I want to have the last list item to have a different color. How can I address it correctly?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GUhhz/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <a><li>AAAA</li></a>
        <a><li>BBBB</li></a>
        <a><li>CCCC</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap li{
    color: green;
    background: blue;

}

.wrap li:last-child{
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the `li` elements are the last (only) children of their respective parent elements. You want to use `.wrap a:last-child li` to target the last `a` in the list, and then its `li` child.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FMbJ9/)

Answer (score 4):

You html is invalid, lists can only have list element children and an anchor is not a list element.
For valid html your css works

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li><a>AAAA</a></li>
        <li><a>BBBB</a></li>
        <li><a>CCCC</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GUhhz/1/

If you have the `a` wrapping the li to make them block like just use css

```
.wrap ul li a{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your html is invalid..

You cannot have `li` elements under `a`,they are only allowed as direct children of `ul` or `ol`, and they are the only allowed elements of those two.. (so `a` are not allowed there..)

If you fix your html by putting the `a` inside of `li` instead of the other way around, it will work.

The importand thing is that `last-child` etc work between elements that share the same parent